# Deploying multiple apps to mule tomcat server

Tags: tomcat, server, mule

In a Mule Documentation I read that if I deploy .war file on an App server

> Each web app runs own mule instance, thereby increasing the size of the webapp

So how can identify the maximum numbers of apps that can run on a single mule tomcat server? And how to determine how many servers would I need deploy around 200 mule apps?

Any help/suggestion please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 200 mule flows or 200 different projects? If it is 200 different flows then it will go into single web application (war).

Number of web apps can be deployed on single tomcat is depends on your system configuration and memory requirement of individual app.

Comment: I have 8GB RAM system and 200 .war files